# Refresh screen not working in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using Modal class of react native for animation. When I opened the modal class and made some changes in my JS then R+R command on emulator was not working even reload command in ctrl+M was also not working. Although it works if we close the Modal and reload. I am using windows and genymotion.

Comment: i have the same issue her on real device. when a modal is open live reload don't refresh the app but it compile it background. did you found a solution ?

Comment: No I did not find the solution but after few tries it started working normally. I dont remember changing anything.